# Tcl/Tk widgets and FocusOut not working as expected on linux

Tags: linux, tcl, tk-toolkit, tile

Do anyone know why FocusOut event is not working on linux?

I have 1 enabled textbox and 3 disabled combobox.
I bind the textbox with FocusOut event where it will call a proc that enables or disables the 3 combobox.

It works perfectly on Windows. However, it doesn't seem to trigger the FocusOut event when this action is done on Linux. One weird thing is that if I click on buttons, FocusOut event seems to be triggered.

Could it be because my combobox are disabled?
But why does it work on Windows?

I really hope someone can help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify -- are you really concerned about focus (ie: where the keyboard sends text) or whether the cursor is over the widget or not? What are you doing to trigger the `<FocusOut>` event -- a special binding to the tab key, you click over some other entry or text widget, ...? And just to be certain, are you talking about a text widget or an entry widget (there is no widget named 'textbox')?

Comment: I'm concern about when user clicks on combobox or text widget after some inputs in the entry widget. Thus I'm using the <FocusOut> event.

Answer (score 1):

I have observed in the past that some window managers steal the focus temporarily from Tk on each button click before setting it back; I suspect that this has to do with the way that key event handling works, but I am unable to check at the moment (due to being on OSX, where things are *different*). Because of the complexities involved, I'd suggest that if you bind to `<FocusOut>`, you should also check whether you get a `<FocusIn>` event shortly after; a little extra delay (e.g., 0.1s) before doing the update of the buttons' disabled status will not hurt.

Or you could hang the code to do the disabling off the [entry widget validation engine](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm#M7), perhaps like this:

```
.e configure -validation focusout -validatecommand doButtonEnableDisable
```

The validation interface is the same for both the old style `entry` and the new style `ttk::entry` widgets. It's also supported by spinboxes. Just be aware that you need to return a boolean true from `doButtonEnableDisable` or you'll reject the change to the entry, and you should take care to ensure that your code does not produce an error or it will disable itself; the docs list the things to watch out for.

Comment: I tried the second suggestion but sadly it doesn't work on linux too. It behaves the same as when I bind my entry widget to <FocusOut>. On the other hand, when <FocusIn> is bind to my entry widget, it does call the proc I wanted it to call.

Any idea why?

Thanks =)